# TestFlight: Team Token Error - Your Team Token is not recognized

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm using TestFlight on my iphone application. But when I run it, I got the following error: "TestFlight: Team Token Error  - Your Team Token is not recognized". Please tell me how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Team Info page in testflight, there is a box holding your team's token.

Are you 100% sure that's exactly the same as in your app?

If it is, perhaps you need to wait a bit for test flight's caches to work through? How recently did you create your team?

Comment: Hi all, I have solved this problem, because when i build the .ipa file, i'm not add App ID of Apple. When i'm correct this, everything is ok. Thanks for help me. :)

Answer (score 3):

We recently had the same problem - while the error message suggests that the App Token is incorrect, it may in fact be that your Bundle Identifier does not match what is in testflight. Check that your Target's Bundle Identifier matches the Bundle Identifier in your app's settings on testflight.

Comment: This also is a correct answer and was the problem I was having. Thanks!

Comment: Bundle identifiers are case sensitive. Making sure that the identifier on Testflight was the exact same as the identifier in Xcode fixed this issue for me. Thanks